# Python numpy array index can be -1?

Tags: python, opencv, numpy

I'm trying out opencv samples from https://github.com/Itseez/opencv/blob/master/samples/python2/letter_recog.py and I need help deciphering this code..

```
new_samples = np.zeros((sample_n * self.class_n, var_n+1), np.float32)
new_samples[:,:-1] = np.repeat(samples, self.class_n, axis=0)
new_samples[:,-1] = np.tile(np.arange(self.class_n), sample_n)
```

I know what `np.repeat` and `np.tile` are, but I'm not sure what `new_samples[:,:-1]` or `new_samples[:,-1]` are supposed to do, with the -1 index. I know how `numpy` array indexing works, but have not seen this case. I could not find solutions from searching.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Python slicing and numpy slicing are slightly different. But in general `-1` in arrays or lists means counting backwards (from last item). It is mentioned in the [Information Introduction](https://docs.python.org/3.4/tutorial/introduction.html#strings) for strings as:

```
>>> word = 'Python'
>>> word[-1]  #last character 
'n'
```

And for [lists](https://docs.python.org/3.4/tutorial/introduction.html#lists) as:

```
>>> squares = [1, 4, 9, 16, 25]
>>> squares
[1, 4, 9, 16, 25]
>>> squares[-1]
25
```

This can be also expanded to numpy array [indexing](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.0/reference/arrays.indexing.html) as in your example.

`new_samples[:,:-1]` means all rows except the last columns

`new_samples[:,-1]` means all rows and last column only

Comment: *"Python slicing and numpy slicing are different."*  That's a potentially misleading statement to begin your answer, because while there are differences, I wouldn't say the use of -1 (which is the subject of the question) is one of them.  Python lists can be indexed with negative values (including -1) and sliced with, for example `:-1` to get all but the last element.

Comment: @WarrenWeckesser, I edited the answer to remove possible confusion for future readers.